# Periodic solutions and existence of singularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm Trying to prove the following:

Let $f$ and $g$ be two vector fields defined in all $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ such that $\langle f(x),g(x)\rangle$ $ = 0$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. If $f$ has one periodic orbit then $g$ has a singularity.

I tried the following:

Let $\gamma$ be the periodic orbit of $f$ and $(x_{1}(t),x_2{t})$ a parametrization of $\gamma$, so $(x_{1}'(t),x_2'{t})$ = $(f_1(x_1,x_2),f_2(x_1,x_2))$ therefore:
$\langle$$(x_1'(t),x_2'(t)),g_1(x_1,x_2),g_2(x_1,x_2)\rangle$ $=$ $0$. But from here, I have no idea how to finish.

Thank You for any help !

Comment: Which $g$ are you using? In the last scalar product you write that the norm of the tangent vector to any point of the orbit is =0.

Comment: sorry for this!! my mistake I will correct it

Comment: now its ok @Avitus

Comment: You mean like $\langle$ $x_1'(t+T),x_2'(t+T),g_1(x_1,x_2)g_2(x_1,x_2)$$\rangle$?

Comment: for singularity you mean a point in the plane where $g=0?$

Comment: yes for singularity I mean $g=0$